# abp suite Navigation properties not working

Tags: abp

I followed https://docs.abp.io/en/commercial/latest/abp-suite/generating-crud-page step by step, of course I using latest abp suite

I added Entity01 and Entity02, Entity02 with navigation property (dependent entity Entity01).
I added Entity01 values:

[image]

After migration, compilation I can't see dependent entity values. Why?

[image]

Comment: Do you have white space in your property names?